# AWS S3 cp command works manually, but not with crontab

Tags: php, ubuntu, amazon-s3, cron, command-line-interface

I have a PHP script that uploads files to an S3 bucket using the PHP `exec()` call. It works perfectly when I run it manually. However, when I run the script through crontab, I get an error

> sh: 1: s3: not found

in my log file.

I am not sure what exactly is going wrong. My cronjob is run as ubuntu and my `.aws` configuration directory is in `/home/ubuntu/.aws`. I have set all the permissions to the max.

Comment: Content of your script should be guessed?

Comment: As @NikolayShevchenko said, could you please share the code to look further?